# Initialize a value when not null (or leave the default if new value is null)

Tags: c#, nullable-reference-types

If I have an object, that has defaults defined so they are not null

```
public class MyObj
{
  public IList<string> SomeList { get; set; }
    = new List<string>();
  ...
  // Other not-nullable properties
  ...
}
```

When I want to create a new instance, and initialize the values

```
var myListThatMightBeNull = GetMaybeNullList();
var newObj = new MyObj
{
  // assign other non-nullable properties
  SomeList = myListThatMightBeNull
};
```

Is there a clean way to assign the value to `SomeList` only if `myListThatMightBeNull` isn't null, and leave the default value otherwise?

Doing this obviously works, it just feels clunky compared to other modern syntax.

```
var newObj = new MyObj
{
  // assign other non-nullable properties
};

if (myListThatMightBeNull is not null)
{
  newObj.SomeList = myListThatMightBeNull;
}
```

Is there some sort of backwards `=??` operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the null coalescing `??` operator while assigning this list.
On the Microsoft website, you can find its documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator)

so you code will be as following:

```
var myListThatMightBeNull = GetMaybeNullList();
var newObj = new MyObj();
newObj.SomeList = myListThatMightBeNull ?? newObj.SomeList;
```

or if you need to use inline initialisation use empty list as default callback

```
var myListThatMightBeNull = GetMaybeNullList();
var newObj = new MyObj
{
    // assign other non-nullable properties
    SomeList = myListThatMightBeNull ?? new List<string>(),
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible by using a full property:

```
public class MyObj
{
  private IList<string> _someList = new List<string>();

  public IList<string> SomeList
  {
    get => _someList;
    set => _someList = value ?? _someList;
  }
}
```

C# 12 (or later) might introduce a `field` keyword for property getters&setters, which will make it easier:

```
public class MyObj
{
  public IList<string> SomeList { get; set => field = value ?? field; }
}
```